# Why are my entries disappearing when {% if category | length %} is added?

Tags: structure, filter, category

Editing an index page that displays all entries within a structure.

Everything displays fine.

I add a category to a few entries and add `{% if category | length %}`and everything disappears as if no entries had a category.

I get no twig errors, so I presume my code is okay.

Here it is, just in case:

```
          {% set entries = craft.entries.section('fellows').relatedTo(category) %}
      {% if category | length %}
        {% if entries | length %}
          {% for entry in entries %}
            {% for matrixBlock in entry.fellowsEntry %}
              {% if matrixBlock.type == 'entryContent' %}

                <a href="{{ entry.url }}" class="portfolio-view bio"> 
                    <div class="portfolio-index inner bio m-white col-md-12">
                        {% for image in matrixBlock.fellowImage %} 
                           <img src="{{ image.getUrl('sq300x300') }} " alt="" class="image-portfolio">
                         {% endfor %} 
                        <h3 class="name text-center p22-ltp">{{ entry.title }}</h3>
                        <hr>
                        <h3 class="org text-center p22-ltp">{{ matrixBlock.organization }} </h3>
                        <hr>
                        {{ category }}
                    </div></a> 

             {% endif %}
          {% endfor %} 
        {% endfor %}   
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Are you setting `category` somewhere?

Comment: My understanding was that I am already in a category page and should have access to the {{ category }} model without having to set it.

Comment: Ah yes good point. My bad...

Answer (score 1):

My `Category URL Formats` was set-up incorrectly. Or rather, I needed to go to `{handle}/{slug}` to see the proper result.